# Virtual directory problem for cruise control.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, virtual-directory

I have downloaded cruisecontrol.net setup and have installed it in `"C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET"`.

It contains a folder called `"webdashboard"` which has aspx page and some other stuff as well.

I want to configure this in my IIS so that I can access it , I tried but it doesn't work , every time I get error that `page you requested is not found`.

I created web site, created virtual directory but none is working.

I have not put anything in `inetpub/wwwroot`.

Can anyone please guide me how can I configure this to work.

Comment: Did any of the answers help? Do you need any further assistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick guide based on my settings:

- Add a virtual directory to Default
  Web Site called "ccnet"
- Map the path to "C:\Program
  Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard"
- Give read permission
- Set execute permissions to Scripts
  Only.

Answer (score 0):

The CruiseControl.NET installer has an option to create the IIS virtual directory as part of the installation process.  I've always used this option, and haven't had a problem with it.  In the future (or if you want to attempt to reinstall your current installation), try allowing the installer to create the virtual directory for you.